# Problems with B.Soup results

Tags: python

so I'm bsoup(never used before) for price scraping, the only thing is is that get 'none' as price results. here's the code:
(dont ask me bout the selenium part, it was the clients request)

```
#imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import tkinter

#page visuals with selenium
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
chrome_options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\scaper")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'./chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.nl/iiyama-GB2730HSU-B1-1920x1080-DisplayPort-HDMI-VGA-USB-verstelbaar/dp/B07CZG35VV/ref=sr_1_16?__mk_nl_NL=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=iiyama&qid=1603039574&sr=8-16')
driver.get('https://m.alternate.nl/iiyama/G-Master-Black-Hawk-G2730HSU-B1-27-inch-Gaming-Monitor/html/product/1358513')
driver.get('https://www.bol.com/nl/p/iiyama-g-master-g2730hsu-b1-gaming-monitor/9200000078741649/?bltgh=v1fqXrRprfFJRH-cwpNNmw.1_31.40.ProductImage')
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.close()

#price analysis with beautifulsoup 
URL = 'https://www.amazon.nl/iiyama-GB2730HSU-B1-1920x1080-DisplayPort-HDMI-VGA-USB-verstelbaar/dp/B07CZG35VV/ref=sr_1_16?__mk_nl_NL=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=iiyama&qid=1603039574&sr=8-16'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:81.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/81.0'
}
page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice")
print(price)

#tkinter results
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with requests and I don't know what headers do, but I figured I would try and help since nobody has answered you.

It looks like it's definitely a problem with the headers you provided because I get a result running this code:

```
URL = 'https://www.amazon.nl/iiyama-GB2730HSU-B1-1920x1080-DisplayPort-HDMI-VGA-USB-verstelbaar/dp/B07CZG35VV/ref=sr_1_16?__mk_nl_NL=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=iiyama&qid=1603039574&sr=8-16'

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find(id="price_inside_buybox")
print(price.text)
```

I would look here: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/

Sorry I couldn't be of any more help.

Comment: No problem! Consider accepting and upvoting? Thank you